# Выводит огромную ошибку, не могу понять что не так

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```python
import telebot
import random
bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
gamep = 0
   
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
# Если пользователь отправил "привет, как тебя зовут?" отвечаем "робот я"
    if message.text == "Привет, как тебя зовут?":
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'img/kto.png')
       bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я бот а че?')
    elif message.text == 'плохое слово':
       gamep += 1
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'img/nono.png')
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не говори плохих слов')
    elif message.text == 'другое плохое слово':
       gamep += 1
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не говори плохих слов')
       if gamep == 3:
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты уже сказал плохое слово уже 3 раза')
           photo = open('img/blzt.png', 'rb')
           bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'По меньше плохих слов говори')
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Теперь сделаю вид что это-го случая не было....Начнем все сначало')
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привеет {message.from_user.first_name})')
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как твои дела?)')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка такая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\админ\Desktop\Telegram\main copy.py", line 42, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6788, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "c:\Users\админ\Desktop\Telegram\main copy.py", line 28, in handle_text
    gamep += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gamep' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Проверьте что токен бота написан правильно без ошибок.

Answer (score 2):

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gamep' referenced before assignment** - вы пытаетесь инкрементровать `gamep`, хотя до этого ей не присвоено ни какое значение.

Чтобы переменная не воспринималась как локальная, нужно добавить её в метод с директивой `global`:

```
def handle_text(message):
    global gamep
```

Answer (score 0):

переместите переменную `gamep` до создания бота

```
import telebot
import random
gamep = 0
bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].